# How to deserialize a very large JSON data directly from stream instead of loading the entire json at once

Tags: c#, json, json.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Incremental JSON Parsing in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9026508/incremental-json-parsing-in-c-sharp)

The following questions are related but don't address (at least directly) the problem I'm trying to solve:

- [Load JSON data stream from text file into objects C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3973878/load-json-data-stream-from-text-file-into-objects-c-sharp)
- [deserializing JSON to .net object using NewtonSoft (or linq to json maybe?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749639/deserializing-json-to-net-object-using-newtonsoft-or-linq-to-json-maybe)

I am trying to deserialize potentially a very large JSON data using [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/). Instead of loading the entire file into memory and parse the JSON using `JObject.Parse(JsonFullString)`, I wish to read from the stream token by token and construct the object graph. I would appreciate any suggestion on how to implement deserialization from stream.

Note: My intent is to replace the following code with better implementation

```
      string jsonData = string.Empty;
      byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
      using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
      {
          int read;
          while ((read = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
          {
              ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
          }
          jsonData = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(ms.ToArray());
       }                    
       JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(jsonData);
       var entities = from e in jObject.Root
                      select e;
```

Answer (score -3):

Nice Idea!

I think what you can do is the following:

1. Create the object first
2. Read the stream in a loop, by chunks, as you are doing now
3. Fore every chunk you've read check if it contains a token (if a comma "," is found within)
4. if no comma found - read another chunk (maybe a smaller one in this case?)
5. Split the pre - comma text (data.split(":");) and with the help of reflection, or hardcoded loop, if you dont need to support every possible object, assign the value to the property
6. continue looping.

Comment: its not that i dont mind the voting that much, but the json parsers ive seen work exaclty like that. it can be nice to know where you people think i was wrong

Comment: Because live is not that easy. Just a simple example `{ "delimeter1": ",", "delimeter2": "}"}`. Also arrays, arrays of arrays, nested objects, escaping non-ascii chars etc.